# Run a single TestNG test in NetBeans 8.1

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, testng

In my custom NetBeans project, I can run single JUnit tests in the NetBeans UI using a combination of an action in the project.xml file and an Ant target in my build.xml. In porting my tests to TestNG, I would like to be able to run single TestNG tests using the NetBeans UI too. Unfortunately this is proving harder than expected. Here's my Ant target:

```
<target name="testng-single" depends="compile-test" description="Run individual testng test" >
<testng failureproperty="test.failed" haltonfailure="yes" outputDir="src/testng/test-output" workingDir="." >
    <classpath refid="classpath.test" />
    <classpath refid="classpath.groovy" />
    <classpath location="${build}"/>
    <classpath location="src/testng"/>
    <classfileset dir="src/testng" includesfile="${test.class}" />
</testng>
<fail message="Tests failed!" if="test.failed"/>
</target>
```

Here is my action:

```
<action name="test.single">
    <script>build.xml</script>
    <target>testng-single</target>
    <context>
        <property>test.class</property>
        <folder>src/testng</folder>
        <pattern>\.java$</pattern>
        <format>java-name</format>
        <arity>
             <one-file-only/>
        </arity>
   </context>
</action>
```

I can right-click a test file and select Test File, but when it runs, it cannot find the class. I see errors along these lines:

```
Includesfile D:\javamarket\ftharness\com.javamarket.testng.donothing.DoNothingTest not found.
```

Ftharness is the top-level directory for my project and src/testng is the directory below this which contains the TestNG tests. I have tried various changes without success. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

in case this helps out anyone looking to solve the same problem: I solved this as follows. It's not great, but seems to work.

Essentially, I use TestNG's ability to consume a test definition as an XML file. I created an ant target along these lines:

```
<target name="testng-single" depends="compile-test" description="Run individual testng test" > 
<copy file="${tst.dir}/TestSingle.xml" overwrite="true" tofile="${tst.dir}/TempTestSingle.xml" > 
<filterset> 
<filter token="CLASS" value="${test.class}"/> 
</filterset> 
</copy> 
<testng failureproperty="test.failed" haltonfailure="yes" outputDir="src/testng/test-output" suitename="TestNG Suite" testname="TestNG Name" workingDir="." > 
<classpath refid="classpath.test" /> 
<classpath refid="classpath.groovy" /> 
<classpath location="${build}"/> 
<classpath location="src/testng"/> 
<xmlfileset dir="${tst.dir}" includes="TempTestSingle.xml" /> 
</testng> 
<fail message="Tests failed!" if="test.failed"/> 
</target>
```

added the following to the project.xml file:

```
<action name="test.single"> 
<script>build.xml</script> 
<target>testng-single</target> 
<context> 
<property>test.class</property> 
<folder>src/testng</folder> 
<pattern>\.java$</pattern> 
<format>java-name</format> 
<arity> 
<one-file-only/> 
</arity> 
</context> 
</action>
```

and added a TestSingle.xml file that looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" > 
<suite name="Single Method Suite"> 
<test name="Single Method Test"> 
<classes> 
<class name="@CLASS@"> 
<methods> 
<include name=".*" /> 
</methods> 
</class> 
</classes> 
</test> 
</suite>
```

With these changes, I can now right-click one of my TestNG java classes and run it.

Hope this helps someone! Martin